# Please replace the blue link colour used in Skeptics Main with a colour with higher contrast

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks

Skeptics recently adopted a link colour that's an especially bright blue. I find it very uncomfortable to read, and I enjoy reading Skeptics questions quite a lot, so this is unfortunate. (Skeptics is very fond of reference links, which is good, and sometimes [large chunks of text are links](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/30672/26699), so this presents a problem for general reading.)

I figure I'm unlikely to be the only one experiencing this visual discomfort, not having super unique eyes. Could the link colour be changed?

The blue link colour is very low contrast by WCAG standards, with a contrast ratio of [2.8 in block quotes](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#rgb%2826%2C%20161%2C%20219%29-on-rgb%28255%2C%20249%2C%20227%29) and [2.9 elsewhere](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#rgb%2826%2C%20161%2C%20219%29-on-rgb%28253%2C%20253%2C%20249%29). For me it winds up looking very glary.

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) has blue links that are only very slightly darker, and yet [would have a contrast ratio here of 3.9](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#rgb%2878%2C%20130%2C%20194%29-on-rgb%28253%2C%20253%2C%20249%29), which is far better. Maybe that would do?